# File does not load css

Tags: php, css

I am working on a website and this is the situation I have:
On the root I opened a folder called "articles", inside that folder I opened another folder called "webdesign" and inside that folder I opened a file called "web-design-templates.php".
The problem I have is that the file "web-design-templates.php" does not load the css although the stylesheet link is on the page.  This is how the stylesheets look:

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Any ideas?

Here is the file directory.

[image]

Comment: `href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">` ... you want to start the path at the root

Comment: Verified that the path exists? Show us your directory structure

Comment: I've posted a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You use a relative path. And that path is from that file you're loading. So use a `/` before the css path to start from your root.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

otherwise you try to load your css from your subdirectory where the file is located.

**Edit:**

Notice from the comment. You use also a wrong include path that is relative and can't work if you are in a subdirectory.

Comment: I noticed he also has `include('includes/header.php');`... might be worth mentioning that the `include_path` set in php does not relate to css includes in html (and javascript, or other resource includes).

Comment: Is there any solution?  Of course if I move it to the root it works perfect but I would like to have everything organized in topics.

Comment: @Tertuleo you shouldn't work in that way that you generate subdirectories. Use rewrites or a simpel CMS-System.